# Freezing a div from horizontal scrolling but letting it scroll vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an outer division(with fixed height and width) which contains two divisions placed vertically occupying equal widths and full height. I want them to scroll simultaneously in vertical direction but only the second one to scroll horizontally. So that essentially the first div is frozen from horizontal scrolling alone. 
within the divs I am using d3 for data visualization using SVG based graphics.

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: I found a solution using position:fixed but that doesn't seem to work due to vertical overflow. fixing the position causes the green div to flow out of the container div. take a look http://jsfiddle.net/gcNte/1/ this solution is what i require if i could get vertical scroll for the overflow in the container div.

Comment: i'm sorry i dont understand:
 
you want to get those two inside the container and both scroll? or just get the vertical scroll, but you need to keep the width of the blue one? or i dont get anything?

Comment: Consider this, I have a container div with fixed width and height. It has two divs 'blue' and 'green' as shown in the code. I add further elements in these two divs on the fly using d3. Now what I want is that I should be able to get a vertical scroll bar in container div so that both the divs are scrollable simultaneously. Now the blue div has a larger width than the container can accommodate so that a horizontal scroll bar will come up but then when it does come I don't want the green div to move i.e it is frozen from horizontal scrolling as is done in the code in the link.

Comment: But the problem with the solution in the link is they have used position:fixed on green element which causes green div to outflow of the container div as is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xY6X/2/)

```
    <style>
div.Container{
   height: 250px;
   border: 2px solid #F00; 
   width: 600px;
    padding: 3px;
    overflow: auto;

    /* POSITION */
    position:fixed;
}

div.Const{
   border: 2px solid #0F0;
   width: 200px; 
    height: 400px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
div.Main{
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  top:0px;
  float:left;
}
    </style>
<body>
<div id="Container" class="Container">
    <div id="Const" class="Const"> 
    </div>
    <div id="Main" class="Main">
    </div> 
</div>
    </body>
    <script>
$('#Container').scroll(function() {
    $('#Const').css('left', $('#Container').scrollLeft());
});
</script>
```

Comment: @sachin92sam is this the right answer? in case, please vote it

Comment: I would have done that already if I had enough reputation! :P

Comment: @sachin92sam you can set it as the accepted answer if you think it is really the answer but, yes, to vote up you need at least 15 reputation.