# Internet Explorer Buggy CSS Left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a html page where I want a div to scroll vertically with the page but not horizontally (rest of the content to disappear under it);

From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036906/freezing-a-div-from-horizontal-scrolling-but-letting-it-scroll-vertically) I found a good answer to this, however I was wondering if there was a way to fix a small bug.

http://jsfiddle.net/nkgsqc1o/

When scrolling left using either the scroll bar's arrow or the arrow keys on the keyboard, the green box goes all spazzy trying to keep up. This doesn't occur in Firefox.

I am wondering if its the jquery code (below) or Internet Explorer itself?

```
$('#Container').scroll(function() {
    $('#Const').css('left', $('#Container').scrollLeft());
});
```

I have tried playing with jquery's animate but it does much the same. I have also tried playing with the "smooth scrolling" setting inside Internet Explorer but that didn't help either.

Comment: I think its about abandoning a javascript solution in favour of pure css. I was playing around with setting position:fixed on the green box, with left, top and bottom all 0px. There's more to do, but it avoids the jarring effect caused in your css vs js battle 

Comment: @ne1410s I wasn't sure it was possible to do just a pure css solution :S
since going fixed normally means I cant scroll vertically or something.

Comment: @user4749485 Your code seems to smooth out the slight movement from moving the scroll bar (quickly) using the mouse, however the jaggedness from using the keyboard's arrow keys or the scroll bar's arrows is still present :(

Comment: @user4749485 Wow that does fix it.... not entirely sure why it works

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkgsqc1o/4/). I have removed jquery and simply used CSS. Hope that helps.

```css
div.Container{
   height: 300px;
   border: 2px solid #F00; 
   width: 800px;
    padding: 3px;
    overflow: auto;
    
    /* POSITION */
    position:fixed;
    z-index : 1;
}

div.Const{
   border: 2px solid #0F0;
   width: 200px; 
    height: 250px;
 float:left;
 position:fixed;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    z-index : -1;
}
div.Main{
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  width: 3000px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  top:0px;
  float:left;
    z-index : 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container" class="Container">
    <div id="Const" class="Const"> 
    </div>
    <div id="Main" class="Main">
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the green box can no longer be scrolled vertically (which needs to happen)